# Tag badge notification goes nowhere

Tags: feature-request, badges, notifications, android-app, android-app-feed

When I signed into the Android App, the feed came up and the top item was a tag badge notification for Meta.  I tapped on space (and wording) and it doesn't do anything.  Seems like it should take me to some badge or profile page.  Tapping on the Meta Icon takes me to the question view.